# How can I find the maximum string type sublists(non-duplicate) with the maximum number of elements?

Tags: python

I want to get the sublists with the maximum number of strings that are not duplicate.

The code below says sets are not hashable which makes sense(`TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`), but I can't find a way around this.

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [{'task'}, {'task', 'time', 'element'}, {'task', 'current', 'time', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task'}, {'task'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'push', 'stack', 'element'}]
find_max_lists = max(k for k,v in Counter(mylist).items() if v>1)
```

Input

```
[{'task'}, {'task', 'time', 'element'}, {'task', 'current', 'time', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task'}, {'task'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'push', 'stack', 'element'}]
```

Output

```
[{'task', 'current', 'time', 'element'},{'task', 'push', 'stack', 'element'}]
```

Input

```
[{'task'}, {'task', 'time', 'element'}, {'task', 'current', 'time', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task'}, {'task'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'element'}, {'task', 'current', 'time', 'element'}]
```

Output

```
[{'task', 'current', 'time', 'element'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without `Counter`. As your list contains set, and sets don't contain duplicate items inside them, you can just check the set-item inside the input list with highest length and create another list with items whose length matches with the highest length.

Here it is :

```
max_len = len(sorted(mylist, key = lambda x: len(x), reverse = True)[0])
output = [k for k in mylist if len(k)==max_len]
# For the second case where the final list may contain same set-item
uniq_list = [set(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in output)]
```

**Output** :

```
[{'time', 'task', 'current', 'element'}, {'task', 'push', 'stack', 'element'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, but is there a way to avoid the extra duplicate like in my second input-output example? Because now I get: [{'element', 'current', 'time', 'task'}, {'element', 'current', 'time', 'task'}]

Comment: Wow, you are fast. That does it! Thanks a lot!